# PCB assembly/mounting components service

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, components, pcb-fabrication

I am looking for advice from experienced people since I am new to PCB design. I have designed a PCB which is a heart rate wearable device based on Arduino Zero board.

I have a small PCB for the Heart Rate Sensor which is a MAX30102 but the PCB manufacturer (JLCPB) did not have the sensor so I asked the board without the sensor.

Do you know about another PCB services which can help me to solder and supply the sensor?
I also looked in PCBWay but they did not have the component too.

My PCB is this:

[image: pcb]

Comment: DigiKey has several thousand in stock (if I am looking at the right part). Why not order them yourself and kit them for the PCB shop? Some PCB Shops will also order the part for you if you supply them a BOM.

Comment: Could you please tell me what pcb shop offer those mentioned services?

Comment: Why can't you solder it yourself? A 2 minute job!

Comment: Could you please tell me if I can do it with solder iron or heating gun?

Comment: @PStechPaul The heart rate sensor is a fine pitch, expensive and delicate part. It also dosen't have exposed pads (to verify the results). Yes it can be done in 2 minutes, but it will require some skill. I've reflowed this part many times, but always with a reflow oven, I wouldn't try it with a hot air pen.

Comment: @imt_blake A hot air gun will likely damage the lens and plastic case. I would recommend a toaster oven (25L 1500W), or a hot plate. You will want a thermocouple temp probe as well to monitor the process.

Comment: It would help to provide a link to the package, which appears to be a 0.8mm pad pitch device. https://www.analog.com/media/en/package-pcb-resources/package/pkg_pdf/olga/21-1048.pdf And a link to the device itself would be helpful as well. https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX30102.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most reputable PCB assemblers will allow you to send your own parts (they call this consignment).

Macrofab for example.

You can also reflow it yourself. You will need solder paste (I recommend lead free), a solder stencil (most PCB services can make them), a thermocouple temp probe, and a hot plate or toaster oven.

I would not try to reflow it with a hot air pen, or heat gun. The case of this part is not very temp resistant, so it will be very easy to damage it in the process.

There are some toaster ovens that produce a good reflow profile right out of the box. The one I use is [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08QRKGJPS). The important specs are: 1500W, convection, and 25L capacity.

You should be aware that this is not an easy part to solder for a beginner. The pads aren't exposed so it will be hard to verify that the solder is melted. They are also very small.